# How to add back ground color for specific rows in excel using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add Back ground color for specific rows. Below are the conditions.
1. Need to add back ground color before search pattern row.

Below is the Excel

```
Name    Depth   TOTAL_AREA  Category     Sub Category_1  Sub Category_2 cell_type
Name1   0       57.1228709  11_DDR          
Name2   1       0.4181432                                               HM
Name3   1       1.4674                                                  HM
Name4   2       0.972       23_Security  Security_Processor sp_wrapper  HM
Name5   2       0.24        23_Security  Security_Processor sp_wrapper  
Name6   2       0.2456      23_Security  Security_Processor sp_wrapper  STD
Name7   2       0.0098      23_Security  Security_Processor sp_wrapper  STD
Name8   1       0.0008984   11_DDR       SHUB               GEMNOC      STD
Name9   1       0.0006654   11_DDR       SHUB               GEMNOC      STD
Name10  1       0.000237    11_DDR       SHUB               GEMNOC      STD
Name11  1       0.0000341   02_GPU       gfx_core           gfx_core    STD
Name12  1       8.16E-05    02_GPU       gfx_core           gfx_core    STD
Name13  1       2.79E-05    08_Modem    modem_offline   modem_lmem_cluster_0    STD
Name14  1   -   0.0000498   02_GPU      gfx_core        gfx_core    
Name15  2       0.018118                
Name16  3       0.0087      23_Security  Security_Processor sp_wrapper  HM
Name17  3       0.000765    23_Security Security_Processor  sp_wrapper  HM
Name18  3       0.008653    23_Security Security_Processor  sp_wrapper  STD
```

Need to add 2 background colours for Name3 and Name15 rows as my search pattern is "23_Security".
Any help is appreciated.

I have tried below script. It is adding background color only specified row.

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler
from xlrd import open_workbook
path = '<input.xlsx>'
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx,'Sheet1')
sf = StyleFrame(df)

categories = ['23_Security']
book = open_workbook(path)

for sheet in book.sheets():

for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
    row = sheet.row(rowidx)
    for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
         for category in categories:
               sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf['Category'] == category],styler_obj=Styler(bg_color='green'))
sf.to_excel('output.xlsx',index=False).save()
```